# writing in a text file with [ ] python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write in a text file with braces.

```
output.write("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t".format(student_iD,user_id,First_name, Last_name,Other_name))
output.write("\n")
```

it writes in the text file with out the braces. What should I add such that I get something like this:

```
[student_id]  [user_id]  [First_name]  [Last_name]  [other_name] in the text file.
```

Comment: Brackets! _Sorry for being pedantic_: consider putting brackets around the curly braces, like such `[{}]`.

Comment: the bracers act like placeholders for the formatting you apply to the string before you write its contents on the file. Enclose them in brackets to get brackets.

Comment: It is not working in my case :(

Comment: @user3419487, it's not working _how_?? What have you tried and what errors/misbehavior did you get?

Comment: No errors... But it is just printing without braces.

Answer (score 0):

Surround those braces with `[]`

```
output.write("[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t".format(student_iD,user_id,First_name, Last_name,Other_name))
output.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
output.write("[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t".format(...)
```

Or place the brackets around the variable names themselves without changing the format string. Then you'll be printing lists, and each of them will consist of only one value.

```
output.write("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t".format([student_iD],[user_id], [First_name], [Last_name], [Other_name]))
```

Comment: @user3419487, what output are you getting?

Comment: I get the output without braces.
student_id   user_id   First_name Last_name  other_name

Comment: @user3419487, impossible. You probably forgot to `close()` or `flush()` the output.

Answer (score 0):

My code

```
output = open('/home/vipul/Desktop/test_data.txt', 'a')
output.write("[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t".format(222,2222,'test',     'test','test'))
output.write("\n")
```

output I got:
     [222]  [2222]  [test]  [test]  [test]

Its working. If you get error paste your output here.

Comment: output.write("[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t[{}]\t{}\t".format([student_id],[user_id],[First_name],[Last_name],Other_name))
output.write("\n")


output I get: 26615188 0000-0002-9903-4248 Michael Baudis ['mbaudis']

Comment: why you are giving  [ ]es in format() method also ? give it only in one place. Give it in the string for now. and one brace is not enclosed with braces.
what is the output you are getting ? paste it here.

Comment: I have tried all kinds... some other problem i guess

Comment: Its weird I see. I am getting the exact output you want in my machine. in 2.x and 3.x . Kindly paste your output you get when you run the code.

Comment: Its working for some outputs. But not all. output i got :  ['2014232'] ['0000-0002-3952-3285'] ['Des'] ['Higgins'] [['Des Higgins']]

Comment: Sme are with out braces.